# displaying array laravel (undenfined index)

Tags: arrays, laravel

My array data
 [{"id":3,"item_id":2,"color_id":1,"image":"uploads/vpvFe1_produk2-2.png","price":"200000","discount":null,"created_at":"2018-03-28 08:11:35","updated_at":"2018-03-28 08:11:35","name":"Liner shirt Catoon Modern"}]

**[my controller]**

```
 class FrontCartController extends Controller
{
   public function accessSessionData(Request $request){
      // if($request->session()->has('my_name'))
      //    echo $request->session()->get('my_name');
      // else
      //    echo 'No data in the session';
        $cart=$request->session()->get('cart.items');
        // $show_item= DB::table('items')
     //    ->join('item_colors', 'item_colors.item_id', '=', 'items.id')
     //    ->select('items.*')
     //    ->where('item_id', $cart->id)->get();
        // echo implode(' ', $cart);
        return view('Palepi.cart')->with('cart', $cart);;
   }
   public function storeSessionData(Request $request, $id){
      // $request->session()->put('my_name','Virat Gandhi');
      // echo "Data has been added to session";
      // $items = Item_color::find($id); 
      $items= DB::table('item_colors')
        ->join('items', 'item_colors.item_id', '=', 'items.id')
        ->select('items.*','item_colors.*')
        ->where('item_colors->id','=' ,$id)->first();
      $request->session()->push('cart.items', $items);

   }
   public function deleteSessionData(Request $request){
      $request->session()->flush();  
       }
}
```

**[my blade]**

[image]

but doesnt work , please help anyone.Thanks

Comment: provide actual code, not screenshot and try to make proper formatting

Comment: how do you pass the data to the view? and I see a foreach cart as cart. Is the foreach needed?

Comment: check my code below

Comment: Pls check @CalinBlaga

Answer (score 1):

```
@if(Session::has('cart'))  
@foreach($items as $item)  
<p>{{ $item->item_colors }}</p>  
@endforeach
@endif
```

$item->item_colors show the value which you store in session..

Comment: But there is no for loop mentioned by the OP in the question

Comment: Please check his screenshot. @MayankPandeyz

Comment: sorry for my mistake @MayankPandeyz

Comment: pls check@Bhoomipatel